# Why is my line renderer not showing up in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a Fruit Ninja style game on Unity 2D and I want to create a trail that follows where the player has "cut". I've tried to instantiate a "cut" object that contains the line renderer every time a user drags. However, the line renderer is not showing up. Can anyone correct any errors or suggest a new method?

```
public class CreateCuts : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject cut;
public float cutDestroyTime;

private bool dragging = false;
private Vector2 swipeStart;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        dragging = true;
        swipeStart = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && dragging)
    {
        createCut();
    }
}

private void createCut()
{
    this.dragging = false;
    Vector2 swipeEnd = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    GameObject cut = Instantiate(this.cut, this.swipeStart, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    cut.GetComponent<LineRenderer>().positionCount = 1 ;
    cut.GetComponent<LineRenderer>().enabled = true;
    cut.GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(0, this.swipeStart);
    cut.GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(1, swipeEnd);
    Vector2[] colliderPoints = new Vector2[2];
    colliderPoints[0] = new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f);
    colliderPoints[1] = swipeEnd - swipeStart;
    cut.GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>().points = colliderPoints;
    Destroy(cut.gameObject, this.cutDestroyTime);
}
```

}

I expect there to be a line, but nothing shows up. There is also a warning stating that the SetPosition(1, swipeEnd) is out of bounds.

**EDIT**: Here are the settings of my cut object

[1st part of cut object settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWUka.png)

[2nd part of cut object settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug3kp.png)

[Positions tab of line renderer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiQMb.png)

Comment: _`positionCount = 1`_ a line with only 1 point?

Comment: Should this be changed to 2 ?

Comment: 2 for 1 line, 3 for 2 lines, and so on.

Comment: I changed the position count to 2 but the line still doesn't show up.

Comment: Another option is to create a particle object, so when your cut object moves, it will move with it and you will have trail kind of effect.

Comment: @Shweta how would I do that? sorry I am still a bit of a unity beginner.

Comment: In your code, Just changing positionCount to 2 draws line perfectly, wherever i swipe on screen. 

    cut.GetComponent<LineRenderer>().positionCount = 2;

And for particles you can create simple particle and make it follow your touch object.
Here is link for particle : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ParticleSystem.html

Answer (score 0):

I want to create a **trail** that follows where the player has "cut".

The word "**trail**" indicates that you should rather use a trail renderer!

Manual: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TrailRenderer.html

API reference: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TrailRenderer.html

Back to your original question:

Your linerenderer probably is rendered but at a random position, because of Vector2 to Vector3 conversion, i dunno your project structure but this can be the case.

Please post a picture with one of your cut gameobject, that holds your linerenderer, and also extend the positions tab on the linerenderer so we can see your points xyz coordinates

Also apply the changes mentioned by commenters, because you really need 2 verticies for a line :P

**Update:**

```
public class CreateCuts : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cut;
    public float cutDestroyTime;

    private bool dragging = false;
    private Vector3 swipeStart;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            dragging = true;
            swipeStart = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            Debug.Log("Swipe Start: " + swipeStart);
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && dragging)
        {
            createCut();
        }
    }

    private void createCut()
    {
        this.dragging = false;
        Vector3 swipeEnd = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Debug.Log("SwipeEnd: " + swipeEnd);
        GameObject cut = Instantiate(this.cut, swipeStart, Quaternion.identity);
        cut.GetComponent<LineRenderer>().positionCount = 2;
        // why is it not enabled by default if you just instantiate the gameobject O.o?
        cut.GetComponent<LineRenderer>().enabled = true;
        cut.GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPositions(new Vector3[]{
            new Vector3(swipeStart.x, swipeStart.y, 10),
            new Vector3(swipeEnd.x, swipeEnd.y, 10)
            // z is zero cos we are in 2d in unity up axis is Y we set it to 10 for visibility reasons tho}
        });
        // Commented out cos atm we are "debugging" your linerenderer
        // Vector2[] colliderPoints = new Vector2[2];
        // colliderPoints[0] = new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f);
        // colliderPoints[1] = swipeEnd - swipeStart;
        // cut.GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>().points = colliderPoints;
        //Destroy(cut.gameObject, this.cutDestroyTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll definitely look into the trail renderer thanks! Also, how do I post pictures into comments? Sorry, this is my first time really using stack overflow

Comment: on the first picture above the graficon there is a text called **Positions**, click on the arrow next to it so we can see the points coordinates :P

Comment: hahahahah sorry I thought you meant the other positions tab. Just added it now

Comment: so from the picture we can see that you have a line but it is going from (0,0,0) to (0,0,1), is it rendered at that position? and i guess it is not your desired position

Comment: there is no line rendered at all, and yeah that's not my desired position :(

Comment: You pause the game so your linerender dont get destroyed right?, because you should really see a line at position (0,0,1) **Tip**: Make an empty gameobject and set its position to (0,0,1) then double click on it

Comment: I rather wrote a script that should work from my phone so please test it

Comment: Hi thanks so much for the code ! However, after trying it there is still no line being rendered. Sorry for the late reply as well.

Comment: Extremely strange, can you like again provide pictures about your linerenderer positions after a random swipe?, and also put a debug.log message here about your 2 mouse positions.(I updated my code with Debug.Log)